# Why is width and height rendering auto when the css clearly defines the property as one hundred percent?

Tags: html, css, height, width

My CSS (SCSS) below show me clearly defining my height and width to 100%.

```
/*
*       SCSS
*/
a#logo {
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     text-decoration: none;
     span#first-name {
          font-size: 4em;
          color: $gray;
          display: inline;
     }
     span#last-name {
          font-size: 4em;
          color: $yellow;
          display: inline;
     }
}​

/*
*       HTML
*/ 
<a id="logo" href=""><span id="first-name">justin</span><span id="last-name">BEAUDRY</span></a>​
```

My problem is that the "a" element is rendering as "auto" even though my SASS clearly defines that the height and width be 100%.

## SOLVED

```
/*
*       SCSS
*/
a#logo {
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     display: block;
     text-decoration: none;
     span#first-name {
          font-size: 4em;
          color: $gray;
          display: inline;
     }
     span#last-name {
          font-size: 4em;
          color: $yellow;
          display: inline;
     }
}​
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems with that:

- The anchor element (a) is an inline element, so you can't specify a size for it without turning it into a block element.
- You have block elements (div) inside an inline element (a), which only works in browsers that support HTML5, and only if you actually use HTML5.

Comment: Thank you. I'll remember that. I guess that would trigger quirks mode?

Comment: @JustinBeaudry: No, but the browser would rearrange the tags or add new tags to turn it into something that could be turned into elements. Typically you would get different result in different browsers.

Comment: "which only works in browsers that support HTML5" — Which is all of them, at least as far as that part of the specification is concerned, at least if you set them to `display: block`

Comment: "only if you actually use HTML5" — Browsers don't care what version of HTML you use. They only care if you have a Doctype that triggers standards mode or not.

Comment: @Quentin: There is still a lot of browsers out there released before html5 even existed.

Comment: @Guffa — A large part of what HTML 5 does is specify things that browsers were doing as error recovery before it existed

Comment: @Quentin: Yes, but allowing block elements in inline elements is not one of them. The error correction prior to html5 was to change the result, not to allow it, and it was unusable as the result wasn't consistent.

Answer (score 4):

`height` and `width` do not apply to non-replaced elements that are `display: inline` (which `<a>` is by default)

Comment: HA! Defining the a element as a block attributed the defined height and width! Thank you.